# Recover data from unresponsive PC using second PC?

Tags: memory, data-recovery

Please forgive any ignorance I display in the course of this question. Is it possible to plug in a second machine somehow to an unresponsive machine to recover data? I'm very desperate right now and am scouring the internet for any possible options. I'm running Ubuntu off a Live CD.

There was a lack of information provided. Here is updated information:

Running Ubuntu off of a live disk. At first the computer was completely unresponsive. After a few hours, the screen woke up, now there's been a black screen for twelve hours with only the mouse cursor showing. So far I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, which didn't work. I have no idea what to use as the second machine; I could use anything Windows or Linux based, loaded on my laptop.

If shutdown isn't an option, is there any other way to access RAM? That's what I'm trying to do by connecting a second machine. I don't even know if this is a viable option, just asking.

Comment: As it is this will be closed - there is not enough information here. What are the machines? In what way is it unresponsive? What have you tried? Give as complete a description as you can.Ignorance is not a big deal - most questions here are asked because of ignorance. :)

Comment: the OP is posting multiple questions for the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is remove the hard drive from the unresponsive system and connect it to a known working system.  Hopefully it's not the hard drive itself with the issue.

Your hard drive, if this system is relatively new (newer than 2004 or so), is likely a SATA hard drive, and desktop computers these days typically have 4 or more SATA ports on the motherboard (big laptops might even have 2 drive bays these days).  So you can connect the drive to an open SATA port on another machine (as well as power from the computer's power supply), boot that computer's working OS, and recover data.

If this drive was formatted under Linux, boot into Linux, otherwise Windows or Linux will be fine.

If you boot into Windows and get a message saying the drive is not formatted, do not format it, try booting into Linux and see if you can mount it from there first.

You can also purchase a USB enclosure, place the hard drive into that, and connect it to another computer in the same manner as an external hard drive or flash drive.

Comment: But right now, there's nothing on hard drive if it hasn't been saved, right? Everything is on RAM, correct? I need to access RAM somehow, if I'm not mistaken, in order to retrieve the data.

Comment: Can I employ the technique in this paper to recover the contents of my RAM? Computer is still on so RAM hasn't been cleared. Or is there any other way you'd suggest?

http://citpsite.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/oldsite-htdocs/pub/coldboot.pdf